# How can we denote list of tuples in argument

Tags: sml, smlnj

In sml, we define lists of integers or strings as arguments by l::ls which helps us to define lists of arbitrary length and then we can compare with = or > or <. How can we denote tuples in similar manner?
e.g.
I can write,

```
fun delete(x,l::ls)=if x=l then delete(x,ls) else l::delete(x,ls)
```

how can I write similarly for tuples?

Note, I even need to compare the individual elements of the tuple: i.e. (a1,b1)>(a2,b2) if b1>b2 so some sortcut that can merely delete like above will not be sufficient.

Tons of Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do pattern matching directly on tuples using the usual form `(x, y)`.

Your `delete` function works on any `'a list` so it is correct for lists of tuples as well. Here is an example which filters a list based on the first values in tuples:

```
fun deleteByFirst(x0, []) = []
  | deleteByFirst(x0, (x, y)::ls) = 
    if x = x0 
    then deleteByFirst(x0, ls) 
    else (x, y)::deleteByFirst(x0, ls)
```

Comment: Hi there, can I similarly pattern match for a datatype location=coordinet of int*int
e.g. coordinet(x1,y1)::coordinet(x2,y2)::ls as a list?

Thank You.